# How to implement parallel mapping for sequences in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, parallel-processing, sequence

I'm trying to implement a parallel implementation for both Iterable and Sequence in Kotlin. I got a little file, it consists of 4 extension functions, but the third one gives me an compiler error:

```
suspend fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.parallelMap(block: suspend(T) -> R) =
    coroutineScope { map { async { block(it) } }.map { it.await() } }

suspend fun <T> Iterable<T>.parallelForEach(block: suspend (T) -> Unit) =
    coroutineScope { map { async { block(it) } }.forEach { it.await() } }

suspend fun <T, R> Sequence<T>.parallelMap(block: suspend(T) -> R) =
    coroutineScope { map { async { block(it) } }.map { it.await() } }

suspend fun <T> Sequence<T>.parallelForEach(block: suspend (T) -> Unit) =
    coroutineScope { map { async { block(it) } }.forEach { it.await() } }
```

The compiler comes back and says that suspension functions can only be called inside suspension functions. Is there a way to implement this?

Edit: fixed bad copy/paste

Edit2: I thought of an implementation:

```
suspend fun <T, R> Sequence<T>.parrallelMap(block: suspend (T) -> R) =
        asIterable().map { coroutineScope { async { block(it) } } }
              .asSequence().map { runBlocking { it.await() } }
```

I was hoping that this would fire all the suspending functions and await them lazily. I'm just not sure if this is safe, or this saves time or not.

Comment: Is the 3rd function supposed to be on an Iterable or a Sequence?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, my bad

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the core semantics of parallel execution for lazy sequences. Your current implementation does not start `block(it)` until the resulting sequence is iterated:

```
suspend fun <T, R> Sequence<T>.parallelMap(block: suspend(T) -> R) =
    coroutineScope { map { async { block(it) } }.map { it.await() } }
```

Consider the following example:

```
sequenceOf(1, 2, 3).parallelMap { it * it }.forEach { println(it) }
```

For this sample the order of execution will be

```
val p1 = async { 1 * 1 } 
val r1 = p1.await()
println(r1)
val p2 = async { 2 * 2 } 
val r2 = p2.await()
println(r2)
val p3 = async { 3 * 3 } 
val r3 = p3.await()
println(r3)
```

Note that the execution of the mapping operations is sequientional, not parallel.

What the compiler tells you is that the lambda of `Sequence<T>.map {}` is performed lazily on-demand outside of the context of the call (read: outside of your coroutine), so you can't use the coroutine you are currently in.

Frankly, I am not sure how one can both perform lazy computation and do it in parallel.

Comment: Fair point. That might be a problem. What if I want to fire all the async blocks, but want to await them lazily. would something like  `suspend fun <T, R> Sequence<T>.parrallelMap(block: suspend (T) -> R) =
        asIterable().mapAsync(block).asSequence().map { runBlocking { it.await() }}` work you think? Edit: mapAsync is `suspend fun <T, R> Iterable<T>.mapAsync(block: suspend(T) -> R) =
    coroutineScope { map { async { block(it) } } }`

Comment: Thinking about this. Does this also mean that the parallelForEach doesn't do anything parallel at all?

Comment: Ye, `parallelForEach` is exactly the same as `parrallelMap` here