# Parallelly consuming a long sequence in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a function generating a very long sequence of work items. Generating these items is fast, but there are too many in total to store a list of them in memory. Processing the items produces no results, just side effects.

I would like to process these items across multiple threads. One solution is to have a thread read from the generator and write to a concurrent bounded queue, and a number of executor threads polling for work from the bounded queue, but this is a lot of things to set up.

Is there anything in the standard library that would help me do that?

I had initially tried

```
items.map { async(executor) process(it) }.forEach { it.await() }
```

But, as pointed out in [how to implement parallel mapping for sequences in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55830626/how-to-implement-parallel-mapping-for-sequences-in-kotlin), this doesn't work for reasons that are obvious in retrospect.

Is there a quick way to do this (possibly with an external library), or is manually setting up a bounded queue in the middle my best option?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html

Comment: As far as I know parallel executions is one of the (few) advantages that Java Stream still has over the Kotlin Sequence. So maybe you could use streams instead.

Comment: @findusl - I've attempted a thing with a parallel stream, but it doesn't seem to work well. I have no good source, but e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30826175/ "There are known problems about processing infinite streams in parallel. In particular there's no way to split the task to equal parts effectively."

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) combined with [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html).

If all work items can be emmited on demand with producer channel. Then it's possible to await for each items and process it with a pool of threads.

An example :

```
sealed class Stream {
    object End: Stream()
    class Item(val data: Long): Stream()
}

val produceCtx = newSingleThreadContext("producer")
// A dummy producer that send one million Longs on its own thread
val producer = CoroutineScope(produceCtx).produce {
    for (i in (0 until 1000000L)) send(Stream.Item(i)) 
    send(Stream.End)
}

val workCtx = newFixedThreadPoolContext(4, "work")
val workers = Channel<Unit>(4)
repeat(4) { workers.offer(Unit) }

for(_nothing in workers) { // launch 4 times then wait for a task to finish
    launch(workCtx) {
        when (val item = producer.receive()) {
            Stream.End -> workers.close()
            is Stream.Item -> {
                workFunction(item.data) // Actual work here
                workers.offer(Unit) // Notify to launch a new task
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your magic word would be `.asSequence()`:

```
items 
  .asSequence() // Creates lazy executable sequence
  .forEach { launch { executor.process(it) } } // If you don't need the value aftrwards, use 'launch', a.k.a. "fire and forget"
```

> but there are too many in total to store a list of them in memory

Then don't map to list and don't collect the values, no matter if you work with Kotlin or Java.

Answer (score -1):

As long as you are on the JVM, you can write yourself an extension function, that works the sequence in chunks and spawns futures for all entries in a chunk. Something like this:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T, R> Sequence<T>.mapParallel(action: (value: T) -> R?): Sequence<R?> {
  val numThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1
  return this
    .chunked(numThreads)
    .map { chunk ->
      val threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)
      try {
        return@map chunk
          .map {
            // CAUTION -> needs to be written like this
            // otherwise the submit(Runnable) overload is called
            // which always returns an empty Future!!!
            val callable: () -> R? = { action(it) }
            threadPool.submit(callable)
          }
      } finally {
        threadPool.shutdown()
      }
    }
    .flatten()
    .map { future -> future.get() }
}
```

You can then just use it like:

```
items
  .mapParallel { /* process an item */ }
  .forEach { /* handle the result */ }
```

As long as workload per item is similar, this gives a good parallel processing.